# Grouping two type of nodes on appositive sites of a canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to set up a canvas with two types of nodes, on appositive sides of the canvas, forming a column(of nodes),without node overlap, while being drag gable. That is when I drag one node down/up the others should move up or down depending on the space available.

I have tried using multiple forces, but I haven't been able to keep an strain column, nor to apply opposite forces on the canvas

```
simulationStart = function (nodes) {
       simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .nodes(nodes).force('collision',d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
return 20;
 })).force("xAxis",d3.forceX(22 ))
.on('tick', tick);

} 
simulationStart(data);
```

Thank you in advance for you time

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my objective by using forceMnaybody() and getting the x coor from the data itself.

```
 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
.force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength())
.force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
return d.x;
}))
.force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
return d.radius;
}))
.on('tick', tick);
```